# Timezones and airing dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I am trying to convert airing date times of TV episodes. The API I use returns me this exact values:

```
Datetime: 2015-05-31 21:00
Country: US
Timezone: GMT-5 +DST
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve the airing datetime in my timezone (Europe/Rome) with the given data. What I'm doing is:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-05-31 21:00', new DateTimeZone('GMT-5 +DST'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Which prints:

```
2015-06-01 04:00:00
```

I have some doubts about being the correct method because other sites that give this same information are saying that the above episode, in my country (IT/Italy) has aired on 1st June, at 03:00 (and not 04:00).

So am I doing correctly, and the sites I'm comparing the results wrong?

Comment: Does that API have documentation, and if so - does it indicate whether `+DST` means that the time zone offset *should be adjusted for DST* or that it has *already* been adjusted for DST?   In other words, is the offset `GMT-5` shown there in the US Eastern time zone (need to apply DST), or in the US Central time zone (DST already applied)?

Comment: Sadly, not. Upon further digging, I found many more websites reporting 03:00 as airing date in my country, and not 04:00. What does this imply, in the code above? I should remove +DST? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, then testing [the conversions](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20150601T03&p1=215&p2=179) based upon your observations, I will assume that the value has *not* yet been adjusted for DST.  I will answer shortly with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same value if you use `new DateTimeZone('GMT-5')`. `GMT-5 +DST` is not a [valid value for a timezone name](https://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) and probably the constructor of class `DateTimeZone` uses as much as it can successfully parse from the argument provided to it.

I think you should parse the value of `Timezone:` "by hand" and adjust the offset by 1 hour if the string ends with `+DST`.

If you know that the returned timezone is always `GMT-5` then you can simply check if the string is `GMT-5 +DST` and use `GMT-4` instead.

Otherwise you can try to parse the received timezone using regular expressions:

```
// The timezone received from the API
$timezone = 'GMT-5 +DST';

$m = array();
if (preg_match('/^GMT([+-]\d+)( \+DST)?$/', $timezone, $m)) {
    if ($m[2] == ' +DST') {
        // Compute the correct offset using DST
        $tz = sprintf('Etc/GMT%+d', -(intval($m[1])+1));
    } else {
        // No DST; use the correct name of the time zone
        $tz = sprintf('Etc/GMT%+d', -intval($m[1]));
    }
} else {
    // The timezone name has a different format; use it as is
    // You should do better checks here
    $tz = $timestamp;
} 
$date = new DateTime('2015-05-31 21:00', new DateTimeZone($tz));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Update:** As @matt-johnson notices, the correct name of the `GMT` time zones is `Etc/GMT` followed by the offset.

`PHP 5.5` and `PHP 5.6` accept and correctly interpret the `GMT` timezones without the `Etc/` prefix. Older versions (`5.3`, `5.4`) throw an exception with message `'DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (GMT-4)'`

I updated the code above to use the correct names. There are some things you must notice in the line:

```
$tz = sprintf('Etc/GMT%+d', -(intval($m[1])+1));
```

- the `+` sign on the [`sprintf()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) format string forces the `+` sign to be produced in front of the number (if the number is positive); for negative numbers a `-` sign is produced with or without it;
- the `+1` in the `intval($m[1])+1` does the `DST` correction;
- the sign of the computed value is changed (notice the `-` in front of it) because of a strange behaviour of the timezone database used by PHP; the behaviour is explained in the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php):

> **Warning**:
>
> Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.
>
> **Warning**
>
> If you disregard the above warning, please also note that the IANA timezone database that provides PHP's timezone support uses POSIX style signs, which results in the Etc/GMT+n and Etc/GMT-n time zones being reversed from common usage.
>   
>   This means `GMT-5` is converted by the code above to `Etc/GMT+5` and `GMT-5 +DST` is converted to `Etc/GMT+4`.

Comment: This is similar to what I was going to write - however, `"GMT-4"` is also not a valid time zone.  It needs to be translated to `"Etc/GMT+4"` (notice the sign change).  Also, it needs to correctly handle values of -1, 0, +1, with and without the DST flag.  For example, `"GMT-1 +DST"` should become `"Etc/GMT"`.

Comment: Alternatively, one could just interpret the input string as UTC, then add/subtract the appropriate number of hours.

Comment: @MattJohnson Could you provide the code you were about to give? Thanks again.

Comment: axiac would appear to be faster than me in PHP.  I usually code in C#.  :)

Comment: Your update looks good.  I think either of our approaches is equally viable.

Comment: @MattJohnson I learned something today, too. I was not aware of the need to change the sign on the old `Etc/GMT` timezones and I had a big surprise on the first run. Then I read the documentation carefully, noticed the warnings on reddish backgrounds :-) and everything went back to the track. Now I see you pointed that out in your initial comment about `Etc/` timezones. I guess I need to go to sleep (it's 23:11 here, I'm on `Etc/GMT-3` :-D)

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  It parses the values you provided, adjusting the input time zone to UTC manually.  Then uses PHP's time zones (which are IANA time zones) to convert to the destination time zone desired.

```
// The values received from the API
$datetime = '2015-05-31 21:00';
$timezone = 'GMT-5 +DST';

// Parse the time zone
$m = array();
preg_match('/GMT([+-]\d+)( \+DST)?/', $timezone, $m);
$offset = intval($m[1]);
$dst = sizeof($m) == 3;

// Adjust for the DST flag
if ($dst) $offset++;

// Apply the offset to the datetime given
$dt = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$dt->setTimestamp($dt->getTimestamp() - ($offset * 3600));

// Convert it to whatever time zone you like
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you! I marked axiac solution as the definitive because of its deep explanation. If I could I would mark both your solutions.